# Unable to create a form with multiple FormFields using REST API for Oracle Eloqua Marketing Cloud Service?

Tags: rest, eloqua

I am testing the `REST API` for `Oracle Eloqua Marketing Cloud Service` method for creating forms using `POSTMAN`. 
`REST API` [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAC/op-api-REST-1.0-assets-form-post.html).

When I give **single form field**, form is getting created. this is my request:

```
POST /assets/form
Content-Type: application/json
```

But when I try to create form with **multiple form fields** like here:

```
  Request body: {
  "type": "Form",
  "createdAt": "1510563258",
  "createdBy": "9",
  "folderId": "7",
  "name": "Form with 3 fields_de-DE1254",
  "updatedAt": "1510563258",
  "elements": [
    {
      "style": "{\"fieldSize\":\"large\",\"labelPosition\":\"top\"}",
      "type": "FormField",
      "name": "Æddrèëss 2",
      "dataType": "text",
      "displayType": "text",
      "htmlName": "address2",
      "useGlobalSubscriptionStatus": "False",
      "validations": []
    },
    {
      "style": "{\"fieldSize\":\"large\",\"labelPosition\":\"top\"}",
      "type": "FormField",
      "name": "Æddrèëss 3",
      "dataType": "text",
      "displayType": "text",
      "htmlName": "address3",
      "useGlobalSubscriptionStatus": "False",
      "validations": []
    }
  ]
}
```

I get error:

```
Status : 500 InternalServerError

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Internal Server Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
        Internal Server Error
    </h1>
        <div>
        There was an internal server error.
    </div>
        <div>
        The error has been logged with log identifier 
            <b>115451307</b>.
        </div>
        <div>
        Please provide this log identifier to technical support.
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please can someone help me with this? Also what is is this log identifier and where can I find it?

Comment: Hi, first of all, I hope you are not including "Request body" in the request body ?
As Eloqua is a SaaS, you have no access to error logs. This log identifier is the unique key for Oracle to retrieve logs in their database. It is useful when contacting Oracle support.

Comment: Hi Clement Duveau, No I am just passing the json in the request body. Do you have idea whats wrong in the json?

Comment: Hi, the error is not giving any information. The best way to debug is to contact Oracle support and give them the log identifier. They will give you the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this and got the solution from support.  You need to put in a unique and negative integer for the field ids.  After doing this, you can send in an array of form fields and they will all get processed in one call.  The response will contain the newly generated ids, if successful.

Here's the modified snippet:

```
Request body: {
  "type": "Form",
  "createdAt": "1510563258",
  "createdBy": "9",
  "folderId": "7",
  "name": "Form with 3 fields_de-DE1254",
  "updatedAt": "1510563258",
  "elements": [
    {
      "id": "-1",
      "style": "{\"fieldSize\":\"large\",\"labelPosition\":\"top\"}",
      "type": "FormField",
      "name": "Æddrèëss 2",
      "dataType": "text",
      "displayType": "text",
      "htmlName": "address2",
      "useGlobalSubscriptionStatus": "False",
      "validations": []
    },
    {
      "id": "-2",
      "style": "{\"fieldSize\":\"large\",\"labelPosition\":\"top\"}",
      "type": "FormField",
      "name": "Æddrèëss 3",
      "dataType": "text",
      "displayType": "text",
      "htmlName": "address3",
      "useGlobalSubscriptionStatus": "False",
      "validations": []
    }
  ]
}
```